# Retrieving a Specific part of string in a Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a requirement. I have some values in a field coming up as :

```
0      [{'name': 'Skyscraper', 'conf': 0.726202309131...

1      [{'name': 'Tree', 'conf': 0.7405981421470642, ...

2      [{'name': 'Castle', 'conf': 0.8047274947166443...

3      [{'name': 'Building', 'conf': 0.94974970817565...

4      [{'name': 'Airplane', 'conf': 0.79357206821441...

5      [{'name': 'Tree', 'conf': 0.8992922306060791, ...

6      [{'name': 'Tree', 'conf': 0.943131983280182, '...

7      [{'name': 'Snowboard', 'conf': 0.8854210376739...

8                                                     []

9      [{'name': 'Sculpture', 'conf': 0.6212946772575...

10     [{'name': 'Tree', 'conf': 0.9138262867927552, ...

11     [{'name': 'Person', 'conf': 0.9718038439750672...

12     [{'name': 'Person', 'conf': 0.9445680975914, '...

13     [{'name': 'Tree', 'conf': 0.8676704168319702, ...

14     [{'name': 'Person', 'conf': 0.9166923761367798...

15     [{'name': 'Tree', 'conf': 0.9771925806999208, ...

16     [{'name': 'Snowboard', 'conf': 0.6349108815193...

17     [{'name': 'Person', 'conf': 0.9804859161376952...
```

if you look at the 8th row I may have empty data coming in too.

The requirement is to extract the confidence and build a heat map out of it

Essentially I need a column with values like

```
0.726

0.740

0.804

0.949
```

... and so on and so forth

Could this be done?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Please start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to ask questions properly using Stackoverflow. Moreover, you should also use this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better understand what YOU need to do as someone with a question in order to get an answer that is relevant to you. While it takes time to ask proper questions on Stackoverflow, it always pays off in the end since you are more likely to get an answer than asking a question in the current format that you are doing it as.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but first input your data into a dataframe.

Once this is done, choose what you want to do with null values. One option is to remove them completely, as seen below. Isolating the column with only the confidence levels is straight-forward from there.

If you would like the 'conf' column returned with a desired number of figures after the decimal place, use the 'apply' method and a lambda expression on the column.

```
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe, assume your list of dictionaries is in a variable 'x'
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
#drop all NaN columns if desired. Otherwise look at pandas documentation for NaN handling options
df = df.dropna()

#isolating the 'conf' column and limiting output to three decimal places
conf_column = df['conf'].apply(lambda x: round(x,3))
```

This will return a pandas series. Seaborn works seamlessly with dataframes/series to create the heatmap. Without knowing more about your end goal, I can't advise on the heatmap, but pandas and seaborn documentation is straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting a key error.

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'conf'